# How do I save data of the user?

Tags: python, django

I have Model:
*models.py*

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='userprofile')
    points = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

*urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', demo),
    url(r'^demo/$', demo),
]
```

*demo.html*

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <button type="submit">+</button>
</form>
```

*views.py*

```
def demo(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
    # I don't understand how I can get "points" from the model   "UserProfile"
    #to add 1 and  to save in the DB
    return render(request, 'app/demo.html')
```

I would like that after pressing on the button points of the user increased one. I really cannot figure it out.

Comment: I know someone's already provided a solution, but I really recommend you read [Django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/) if you haven't already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
def demo(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        profile.points += 1
        profile.save()
        return render(request, 'app/demo.html', {"user":request.user,
                                                 "profile":profile)
```